# Вывод результата с многомерного массива

Tags: php

Добрый день извините за глупый вопрос но не получается преобразовать массив :
дан массив:

```
$in = [
    ['parent_id' => 1,
        'child_id' => 1
    ],
    ['parent_id' => 1,
        'child_id' => 2
    ],
    ['parent_id' => 2,
        'child_id' => 3
    ]
];
```

Необходимо преобразовать в :

```
 $out = [
    1 => [1,2]
  2 => [3]
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете попробовать что то типа

```
$out = array()

foreach ($in as $item):
$out[].= $item['parent_id'], $item['child_id']
endforeach;
```

echo var_dump($out)

состряпал на коленке, но должно помочь